# SSE shifting integers

Tags: c, gdb, sse

I'm trying to understand how shifting with SSE works, but I don't understand the output gdb gives me. Using SSE4 I have a 128bit vector holding 8 16bit unsigned integers (using `uint16_t`). Then I use the intrinsic `_mm_cmpgt_epi16` to compare them against some value, this function puts in all 0 or 1 bits into the bits used to store the ints. So far so good, using gdb I get:

```
(gdb) p/t sse_res[0]
$3 = {1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000, 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000}
```

Then I would like to shift them to the right (is that correct?) so I just get a numerical value of 1 in case it's true. GDB then gives me an output which I don't understand:

```
(gdb) p/t shifted
$4 = {11101000000000010010000000000000110000000000000000011, 100111000000000001011000000000001001000000000000001111}
```

It's not even of the same length as the first, why is this? Just to try it out I used the following intrinsic to shift it one bit to the right:

```
shifted = _mm_srli_epi16(sse_array[i], 1);
```

I expected it to shift in just one zero at the right end of every 16bit block.

**Update:**

I wrote a small example to test the thing with the bitmask, it works fine, but I still don't understand gdbs behavior:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <tmmintrin.h> 
#include <smmintrin.h>

void print128_num(__m128i vector)
{
    uint16_t *values = (uint16_t*) &vector;
    printf("Numerical: %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i \n", 
           values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4], values[5], 
           values[6], values[7]);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    uint16_t nums[] = {1, 57, 33, 22, 88, 99, 9, 73};

    __m128i *nums_sse = (__m128i*)(&nums);
    print128_num(*nums_sse);

    // vector of 42
    __m128i mm42 = _mm_set1_epi16(42);

    __m128i sse_res = _mm_cmpgt_epi16(*nums_sse, mm42);
    printf("Result of the comparison\n");
    print128_num(sse_res);

    // bitmask
    __m128i mask = _mm_set1_epi16(1);

    __m128i finally = _mm_and_si128(sse_res, mask);
    printf("Result of the masking\n");
    print128_num(finally);

    uint16_t* sse_ptr = (uint16_t*)(&finally);

    uint32_t result = sse_ptr[0] + sse_ptr[1] + sse_ptr[2] + sse_ptr[3]
                    + sse_ptr[4] + sse_ptr[5] + sse_ptr[6] + sse_ptr[7];

    printf("Result: %i numbers greater 42\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fff5fbff3b0) at example_comp.c:44
44      printf("Result: %i numbers greater 42\n", result);
(gdb) p/t sse_res
$1 = {11111111111111110000000000000000, 1111111111111111000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111}
(gdb) p/t mask
$2 = {1000000000000000100000000000000010000000000000001, 1000000000000000100000000000000010000000000000001}
(gdb) p/t finally
$3 = {10000000000000000, 1000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000001}
(gdb) p result
$4 = 4
(gdb)
```

My gdb version: `GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1472) (Wed Jul 21 10:53:12 UTC 2010)`

Compiler flags: `-Wall -g -O0 -mssse3 -msse4 -std=c99`

Comment: I think the correct approach would be ANDing them with 1.

Comment: Yes came in my mind too.. However I still don't know what's going on :( But thx for the hint. I'm also wondering which one is faster..

Comment: And I need something to print all the bits, but haven't found it so far.. it seems that gcc is omitting some bits in some cases..

Comment: I would expect that instruction to shift one zero in at the left end of every block. That still doesn't explain what you're seeing.

Comment: I would expect to see what you think you should, and that's what I do see when I use gdb on a program with shift intrinsics like you describe.  So something odd is going on -- either you're not doing what you think you are or something else.  Try posting the actual code that you're try to use gdb on, the actual compile flags, and the actual gdb commands.

Comment: I can print the stuff in numbers using printf, but I also would like to be able to see the individual bits.

Comment: Instead of ANDing with 1, you can subtract from zero.  If you want to accumulate a sum of elements that have their value true, do it with `_mm_sub_epi16`.  If you need a `set1(1)` constant sitting around for some other reason, by all means use `_mm_and_si128`.  On Intel, `PAND` can run on more ports than `PSUBW`.  Intel CPUs can only run `PSRLW xmm, 15` on one port, but it is still a single-uop instruction with single cycle latency and throughput, so **_mm_srli_epi16  should work for this.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do here, but maybe you can clarify it for us.

So, you have 8 *signed* integers packed in each of two variables, which you test for greater than. The result looks like it shows that the first 3 are greater, the next is not, the next 3 are greater, the last is not. (_mm_cmpgt_epi16 assumes signed integers in the reference I found.)

Then you want to tell if "it" is true, but I'm not sure what you mean by that. Do you mean they are all greater? (If so, then you could just compare the result against MAX_VALUE or -1 or something like that.)

But the last step is to shift some data to the right piecewise. Notice that is not the same variable as sse_res[0]. Were you expecting to shift that one instead?

Without knowing what was in the data before shifting, we can't tell if it worked correctly, but I assume that gdb is omitting the leading zeroes in its output, which would explain the shorter result.

```
0000000000011101    29    was 58 or 59
0000000000100100    36    was 72 or 73
0000000000011000    24    was 48 or 49
0000000000000011     3    was  6 or  7
0000000000100111    39    was 78 or 79
0000000000010110    22    was 44 or 45
0000000000100100    36    was 72 or 73
0000000000001111    15    was 30 or 31
```

Do these numbers look familiar?

Update:

Thanks for the updated code. It looks the integers are packed in the reverse order, and the leading zeroes left off in the gdb output.

Comment: Thx for the quick answer :) _mm_cmpgt_epi16 is for signed integers, but I could not find a corresponding function for unsinged ints.. give me a mom and I'll check my program again