# SSE intrinsics bit shifting to the right

Tags: c++, sse, bit-shift, intrinsics

I'm trying to bitshift integers to the right using intrinsics. The code below tries to do that but the output doesn't look as expected, maybe I'm loading the numbers incorrectly or using the wrong intrinsic function. Here's the output:

```
 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 0
 512 1024 2048 4096 8192 16384 32768 0
 0 8192 0 16384
 8 0 16 0
```

I did try looking at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177946/sse-shifting-integers) but that doesn't even try using the [bitshift instructions with SSE intrinsics](http://math.nju.edu.cn/help/mathhpc/doc/intel/cc/mergedProjects/intref_cls/common/intref_sse2_int_shift.htm).

Here's the complete code (compile with SSE2 flag).

```
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void print_16_num(__m128i var)
{
    uint8_t *val = (uint8_t*) &var;
    printf(" %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i \n",
           val[0], val[1], val[2], val[3], val[4], val[5], val[6], val[7],val[8], val[9], val[10], val[11], val[12], val[13], val[14], val[15]);
}
void print_8_num( __m128i var)
{
    uint16_t *val = (uint16_t*) &var;
    printf(" %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i \n",
           val[0], val[1], val[2], val[3], val[4], val[5], val[6], val[7]);
}
void print_4_num( __m128i var)
{
    uint16_t *val = (uint16_t*) &var;
    printf(" %i %i %i %i \n",
           val[0], val[1], val[2], val[3]);
}
int main()
{
    __m128i _16 = _mm_set_epi8( 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1);
    print_16_num(_mm_srli_si128(_16,1));

   __m128i _8 = _mm_set_epi16( 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1);
    print_8_num( _mm_srli_si128(_8,1));

    __m128i _4 = _mm_set_epi32( 128, 64, 32, 16);
    print_4_num( _mm_srli_si128(_4,1));

    _4 = _mm_set_epi32( 128, 64, 32, 16);
    print_4_num( _mm_srli_epi32(_4,1));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: According to the documentation you referenced, `_mm_srli_si128` [shifts by bytes, not bits](http://math.nju.edu.cn/help/mathhpc/doc/intel/cc/mergedProjects/intref_cls/common/intref_sse2_int_shift.htm#slli_si128).

Comment: @RaymondChen Oh, no wonder it doesn't work. So I'm guessing the link (to the other stackoverflow question) is the only way to shift by bits?

Comment: afaik only shifting a 128-bit value shifts by bytes, 64,32,16 use bits. I guess the designers questioned what business you would have shifting such a large value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the _mm_set_epi* functions, they accept their parameters as the most significant item first.

For example, the first statement,

`__m128i _16 = _mm_set_epi8( 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1);`

will load the variable with this value:

```
0x80402010080402018040201008040201
 (128,64,32 ...)
```

Then you shift that 128-bit value right 1 *byte* with `_mm_srli_si128(_16,1)` and you get

```
0x00804020100804020180402010080402
```

When you read the individual byte values, byte[0] is the least significant byte, which would be the one farthest to the right. (so it prints 02 04 08 etc...)

Same thing goes for the other statements, although I think you want to cast to `uint32_t*` inside the `print_4_num` function rather than `uint16_t*`.

For the last one, `_mm_srli_epi32(_4,1)` will shift the value

```
0x00000080000000400000002000000010
       (128)   (64)    (32)    (16)
```

right once bit and it will become

```
0x00000040000000200000001000000008
```

But it will print "8 0 16 0" because you are reading 16-bit values and not 32-bit values in the `print_4_num` function:

```
0x0000 0040 0000 0020 0000 0010 0000 0008
     (not used)        [3]  [2]  [1]  [0]
```

For an easy reference to see what functions do what, check out the Intel Intrinsics Guide:

https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/

Comment: I just had to recast the `print_4_num` and works fine for that, I needed only 32-bits anyways. thanks.